# Is Google login with Firefox broken?

Tags: support, login, google, google-chrome, firefox

Is login with Firefox broken? I am logged in my Google account in Firefox (version 102.0 64 bit) and if I try to log into Stack Overflow using the Google Sign-in button I go in a page that says:

> Request lacked state: May have been forged

If I use Chrome as the browser it works fine.

In case it matters: It was a fresh install of Firefox on a machine that did not have Firefox before. I am on a Mac Monterey

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: probably the new sec features in todays update

Comment: @nbk:Is there anything I can do or my side?

Comment: as far as i understand it firefox now refuses cookies from other sides, so i would start there and deisable it

Comment: @nbk: I have set stack overflow as allowed exception already. Anything else to configure?

Comment: disable it and see if it works, who knows what they changed

Comment: @nbk: I have disabled it. It does not work

Comment: use another browser for the time. Also addons antivirus programs and other could block

Comment: I was on 101.0.1 and there login with Google still worked. And now updated to 102.0 and Google inlog still works. Both tests done in private mode (so that is without any prior cookies / localstorage / cache etc.

Comment: @rene: I did a fresh install of Firefox. Could you try that? May be the update kept settings that allow the flow to work

Comment: Can you add some system information? E.g., operating system, incl. distribution/edition and version. Approximate geographical location. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)

Comment: Weren't there some changes with Google this month, now always requiring [two-factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication)?

Comment: Maybe try [resetting Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems). It's extreme, but it might solve the problem

Comment: I was able to login with 102.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2. I use 2FA for my Google logins however, so that may have something to do with it.

Comment: Some sources for the requirement: *[Google will soon make two-factor authentication mandatory](https://www.techradar.com/news/google-will-soon-make-two-factor-authentication-mandatory)*, *[Google will soon enforce the use of two-step verification for Google accounts](https://www.ghacks.net/2021/05/07/google-will-soon-enforce-the-use-of-two-step-verification-for-google-accounts/)*, and *[Google to Turn on Two-Factor Authentication by Default for Users](https://editorialge.com/google-two-factor-authentication-by-default/)*

Comment: Though I was able to log into my Google account today *without* two-factor authentication. But I think I saw some message this month about it becoming mandatory within a few weeks.

Comment: I can ***not*** reproduce the problem. I tried with a (fresh) install of Firefox (32 bit version by default for unknown reasons) on [Windows 10 Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Baseline_editions) 64 bit (current with this month's [Windows Update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Update)) running inside VirtualBox 6.1.30 on [Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) (used for [configuring a mechanical keyboard](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2021/12/24/rapoo-mechanical-keyboards-gotchas-and-setup/) with macros).

Comment: The Windows 10 system had never had Firefox installed before. The Firefox version is 102.0 (current/up to date).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I am on a Mac and have installed the Firefox 102.0 64 bit

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I added screenshots of my Firefox settings

Comment: Sadly there is no answer so far. I do encounter the same issue on my FF 107.0 on Manjaro Linux - I do have the standard settings on security.

Answer (score 4):

There is already a question on meta SE which has many answers. For my issue it was due to different time settings (my laptop was in the future due to incorrect time settings).

I would encourage you to have a look into the answers there if the issue still exists (or if you landed here by a google search like me):
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380225/347733